# Choosing or filtering columns based on ranks of multiple fields in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.4, rank

In one of the tables, I have multiple fields with a rank field against them. All these fields have a common grouping attribute against which I need to find the best ranked column value which can exist in any of the records of the group. For example, let's consider the data below:

```
+---------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+----------------------+------------+
| Country |     City      | City_Rank |     Artist      | Artist_Rank |        Movie         | Movie_Rank |
+---------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+----------------------+------------+
| USA     | Las Vegas     |         2 | Louis C.K       |           2 | Justice League       |          3 |
| USA     | New York City |         3 | Michael Flynn   |           3 | IT                   |          1 |
| USA     | Los Angeles   |         1 | Matt Lauer      |           1 | Get Out              |          2 |
| UK      | Leeds         |         2 | Jack Maynard    |           3 | Beauty and the Beast |          2 |
| UK      | Manchester    |         3 | Charlie Gard    |           1 | Wonder Woman         |          1 |
| UK      | London        |         1 | Shannon Mathews |           2 | Logan                |          3 |
+---------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+----------------------+------------+
```

Now I need the Rank 1 of `City`, `Artist` and `Movie` Grouped by the `Country` in the single record. So the expected output is:

```
+---------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| Country | Best_Ranked_City | Best_Ranked_Artist | Best_Ranked_Movie |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| USA     | Los Angeles      | Matt Lauer         | IT                |
| UK      | London           | Charlie Gard       | Wonder Woman      |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I have many more attributes against which I have the rank field. I can arrive at the desired output by forming multiple datasets of the above with a filtering condition for each ranked field (where rank=1) and then joining these datasets by the group field.

However, this is quite a costly affair due to millions of records in the table, and filtering and joining this dataset multiple times doesn't seem to be the best way to solve this. I have arrived at the ranks for each field using a `Rank()` windows function by applying some business logic over it.

I would wish further to solve this problem using Window function only if possible.

Comment: This sounds like a SQL question but the code is html formatted.  If it is an sql question, can you post the SQL you are needing help with?  If not perhaps some clarification to what exactly would help.

Comment: I have reformatted to ASCII tables - I guess that's what you meant to have here?

Answer (score 1):

> I have arrived at the ranks for each field using a Rank() windows
>   function by applying some business logic over it.

I guess that there is some query which calculates ranks and then does [a pivot operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) in order to generate a summary table shown in the question.
It would be good to eliminate the pivot operation so that the input data geneerated by this query would look something like this:

```
| country | category |            cat_value | rank_value |
|---------|----------|----------------------|------------|
|      UK |   Artist |         Jack Maynard |          3 |
|      UK |   Artist |      Shannon Mathews |          2 |
|      UK |   Artist |         Charlie Gard |          1 |
|      UK |     City |                Leeds |          2 |
|      UK |     City |           Manchester |          3 |
|      UK |     City |               London |          1 |
|      UK |    Movie |                Logan |          3 |
|      UK |    Movie | Beauty and the Beast |          2 |
|      UK |    Movie |         Wonder Woman |          1 |
|     USA |   Artist |            Louis C.K |          2 |
|     USA |   Artist |        Michael Flynn |          3 |
|     USA |   Artist |           Matt Lauer |          1 |
|     USA |     City |            Las Vegas |          2 |
|     USA |     City |          Los Angeles |          1 |
|     USA |     City |        New York City |          3 |
|     USA |    Movie |       Justice League |          3 |
|     USA |    Movie |                   IT |          1 |
|     USA |    Movie |              Get Out |          2 |
```

If this is not possible, then this resultset can be unpivoted using:

```
SELECT Country, 'City' as category, City as cat_value, City_Rank as rank_value
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Country, 'Artist' as category, Artist as cat_value, Artist_Rank as rank_value
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Country, 'Movie' as category, Movie as cat_value, Movie_Rank as rank_value
FROM Table1
```

---

If you unpivot this table, then picking items with rank=1 is very easy, just do:

```
SELECT * FROM unpivot_table WHERE rank_value = 1
```

and then another pivot can be done on it's results.

---

The final query may look like this (live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/05e53/5)

```
With unpivot_me As (
SELECT Country, 'City' as category, City as cat_value, City_Rank as rank_value
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Country, 'Artist' as category, Artist as cat_value, Artist_Rank as rank_value
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Country, 'Movie' as category, Movie as cat_value, Movie_Rank as rank_value
FROM Table1
)


SELECT Country,
       Max( case when category = 'City' Then cat_value End) As Best_Ranked_City,
       Max( case when category = 'Artist' Then cat_value End) As Best_Ranked_Artist,
       Max( case when category = 'Movie' Then cat_value End) As Best_Ranked_Movie
FROM unpivot_me
WHERE rank_value = 1 
GROUP BY Country

| country | best_ranked_city | best_ranked_artist | best_ranked_movie |
|---------|------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|      UK |           London |       Charlie Gard |      Wonder Woman |
|     USA |      Los Angeles |         Matt Lauer |                IT |
```

Comment: Thanks for your revert. I haven't applied pivot operation to arrive at the dataset. The data was there is my base table as shown in my post without the rank fields. I have arrived at ranks based on some business logic.

Comment: To add to my earlier comment : My table has millions of records and I am looking to rank roughly 8-9 fields. To my understanding union of this dataset 8-9 times will be very expensive and probably will be similar to filtering the datasets with rank 1 and then joining them.

Comment: Yes, unpivoting will be very expensive. For this reason it would be better to change the query that calculates ranks and assigns them to values is such a way, that it generates a resultset rowwise but not columnwise as it does now (and as shown in the question). In other words - the query that assigns ranks must be rewritten too.

Comment: Was able to solve it using window funtion with the same ranks. Have posted the answer after trying on sqlfiddle. Will try on actual data after the vacations. Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Used the window function max() and within it placed a case condition where the ranks are 1  partitioned by country. This fetched first rank values for the desired columns against all the countries. Later filtered it using one of the ranked field with value 1 (could have filtered using any of the available rank field). Here is the SQL : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/05e53/18

```
With T1 as (
select Country, max(case when City_Rank =1 then City else '' end) 
over (partition by Country) as Best_Ranked_City, City_Rank, 
max(case when Artist_Rank =1 then Artist else '' end) 
over (partition by Country) as Best_Ranked_Artist, max(case when 
Movie_Rank =1 then Movie else '' end) 
over (partition by Country) as Best_Ranked_Movie 
from Table1
  )
select Country, Best_Ranked_City, Best_Ranked_Artist, Best_Ranked_Movie 
from T1 where city_rank=1;
```